# Internet connection problem wifi working fine but unable to ping anything?

Tags: snow-leopard, network, wifi, macbook-pro

I just came to a different country and suddenly I am having strange issues with my macbook air 2012's wifi. It seems to detect the wifi networks without issue but refuses to load any webpages or connect to dropbox, app store etc. I tried pinging some websites then I tried pinging 10.10.10.1 but i had no success. It works fine on all the other devices in the home and when I checked the dhcp client list on the router it listed the mac and its ip address. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Just out of interest, what country?

Comment: I had my MBA in USA + Germany + Spain...and it works fine so I am tempted to say it is not country but the ISP.

Comment: Just to be sure: You tried to connect do different wifis? Or do you have the issue only on one single wifi network?